# SQL Azure DTU Spike when adding tables to Linq to SQL DBML

Tags: visual-studio, linq-to-sql, azure-sql-database

Recently I noticed when I drag and drop tables to my DBML file in Visual Studio, I get notifications from SQL azure DB that my DTU percentage is jumping to 100%. Are there any suggestions or tips to prevent this (other than bumping my DTUs up)?

Query generated when dragging and dropping causing the spike is the following:

```
(@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_2 nvarchar(4000))SELECT
db_name() AS [Database_Name],
SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.schema_id) AS [Table_Schema],
tbl.name AS [Table_Name],
cstr.name AS [ForeignKey_Name],
cfk.name AS [Name],
fk.constraint_column_id AS [ID],
crk.name AS [ReferencedColumn]
FROM
sys.tables AS tbl
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.periods as periods ON periods.object_id = tbl.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.tables as historyTable ON historyTable.object_id = tbl.history_table_id
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys AS cstr ON cstr.parent_object_id=tbl.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fk ON fk.constraint_object_id=cstr.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS cfk ON fk.parent_column_id = cfk.column_id and fk.parent_object_id = cfk.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS crk ON fk.referenced_column_id = crk.column_id and fk.referenced_object_id = crk.object_id
WHERE
(cstr.name=@_msparam_0)and((SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.schema_id)=@_msparam_1 and tbl.name=@_msparam_2))
ORDER BY
[Database_Name] ASC,[Table_Schema] ASC,[Table_Name] ASC,[ForeignKey_Name] ASC,[ID] ASC
OPTION (FORCE ORDER)
```

Comment: Azure portal now has some performance tips,one of them is showing DTU usage over a period of time for individual queries.. can you try checking if this queries are really the cause

Comment: Let share this with more people and try to find some help. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I used the performance insights in Azure and narrowed it down, definitely is this query when adding a table to DBML.

Answer (score 2):

I shared this thread with some Microsoft Engineers and the following recommendations came as result:

Update the following statistics:

```
 UPDATE STATISTICS sys.syscolpars
 UPDATE STATISTICS sys.sysschobjs
 UPDATE STATISTICS sys.syssingleobjrefs
 UPDATE STATISTICS sys.sysiscols
 GO
```

See if the following query option helps.

```
OPTION (USE HINT('FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION'))
```

A possible cause of this issue explained [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/4#issuecomment-324828895).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will update statistics and try to see if this solves the issue. I can't use the option clause since the query is generated behind the scenes.

Comment: Doesn't appear update stats did any help. Still running into the same issue today.

Comment: At this time I have not received more workarounds. A manager on SQL Azure team told me he will contact Linq team about this issue.

Comment: Thanks. It is strange this just seemed to start after updating my VS2017 to 15.3. Not sure if it is related.

Comment: Thank you for anything you can add describing this issue.

Comment: Hi Al - if you can't add the option clause, can you test using the legacy CE database scoped configuration instead (in a test environment)?  Use ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION = ON.  Then test to see if the workload performance is still off.

Comment: Has there been any updates on this? I still get DTU spikes when adding tables from server explorer to the DBML designer file